# error message "format ‘%ld’ expects argument of type ‘long int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’"

Tags: c, recursion, factorial

I am writing a simple program to find the factorials for the first 'n' integers. But there is this error that i am encountering when compiling it. Even thought the return type of fact() function is long int, the error still persists.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<30;i++)
        printf("%ld\n", fact(i));
    return 0;
}

long int fact(int n){
    if(n==0)
        return 1;
    else 
        return (long)(n*fact(n-1));
}
```

Error:

```
fourth.c:7:3: warning: format ‘%ld’ expects argument of type ‘long int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
printf("%ld\n", fact(i));
^
fourth.c: At top level:
fourth.c:11:10: error: conflicting types for ‘fact’
long int fact(int n){
         ^
fourth.c:7:19: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘fact’ was here
printf("%ld\n", fact(i));
               ^
```

Comment: Why do you cast to `long` here: `return (long)(n*fact(n-1));` This is not necessary, nor recommended!

Comment: I initially tried without typecasting, got the above error. Thought casting it would solve the error, but obviously it didn't. 
I forgot to remove while pasting it here. Only noticed it now.
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to include function prototype before `main`. Either include a prototype

```
long int fact(int n);
```

or move your function definition before `main`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

long int fact(int n){
    if(n==0)
        return 1;
    else
        return (n*fact(n-1));
}

int main(){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<30;i++)
        printf("%ld\n", fact(i));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to provide a forward declaration for `fact`

```
long int fact(int n);
int main(){
    // body
}
long int fact(int n) {
    // body
}
```

Without this, ansii C assumes a function without a prior declaration or implementation will return `int`

Comment: ...and for the printf problem, just remove the `l` after the `%`.

Comment: @JohnZwinck No, the `printf` problem is caused by the lack of a declaration for `fact`. The format should not be changed, because `fact` returns a `long int`.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I don't think this is required (or correct).  `fact` does return `long int`; providing the forward declaration should be all that is required

Comment: Are you're right of course.  Goes to show you how long it's been since I used compiler options that allowed implicit function declarations!